# Перенаправление addon domain без www с http на https

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Я пытаюсь перенаправить addon домен (включая все ей принадлежащие страницы) с http://mysite.com на https://mysite.com.

Перепробовала кучу вариантов.

Ничего не получается, т.к. возникает циклическая переадресация.

При этом http://www.mysite.com перенаправляется на https://www.mysite.com прекрасно.

Используемое решение:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s ^www\.([^#]+)#(?:off|on(s)) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Как перенаправить http://mysite.com на https://mysite.com?

Comment: Уточнение: При этом http: //www.mysite .com перенаправляется прекрасно не на https: //www.mysite .com, а на https: //mysite .com

Answer (score 1):

Администратор сервера дал решение, может кому пригодится. Это решение переадресует домен с ввв и без ввв к одному адресу https:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```